# Obtaining depth image from 2D image

Tags: matlab, opencv, video, image-processing, computer-vision

Considering [this example](http://www.imagesocket.com/photos/guest/2725930), is there an efficient method for obtaining depth image (b) from 2D image (a)?

I know DIBR can be used, but are there any other methods ?

Comment: This seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075743/separating-left-eye-and-right-eye-views-from-3d-video (although not an exact duplicate). You should really fix issues with that question before asking more questions which need the same things improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `DIBR can be used` is wrong. DIBR is a method that works with 3D videos, ***using*** the depth image to enhance the 2D view. It is not fully automated, you need to supply the depth map by hand for DIBR to work.

You can, however, use 2 cameras to obtain 3D information from 2 x 2D; or use **2D video** to ***estimate*** depth from pixel motion. Some other approaches use perspective information of the 2D image to imitate human understanding of depth - like roads, buildings.

In conclusion, depth map generation from plain 2D image is a harder problem than that of stereo vision, or infrared projectors used in depth sensors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me